# Query Taking Longer Time to Run

Tags: mysql

I have created a query to fetch the non selling product.Here We have two main tables one is product table and second is order_product table. To fetch non selling product i want to fetch those product from product table which does not exist in order_product table. This query works fine on localhost, but when i take this on main server it takes longer time and due to this timeout happen. How could I boost the speed of this query or optimized my query.

```
  SELECT p.date_added, p.model, p.status, p.quantity, ptc.category_id, pd.name AS product_name, cd.name AS category_name FROM (`product` p INNER JOIN `product_description` pd ON p.product_id= pd.product_id) INNER JOIN (`product_to_category` ptc INNER JOIN `category_description` cd ON ptc.category_id = cd.category_id) ON p.product_id = ptc.product_id 
      WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM `order_product`) 
            ORDER BY p.quantity DESC LIMIT 1,100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the other version of the query without using the `not in`

```
SELECT
p.date_added, 
p.model, 
p.status, 
p.quantity, 
ptc.category_id, 
pd.name AS product_name, 
cd.name AS category_name 
FROM `product` p 
INNER JOIN `product_description` pd ON p.product_id= pd.product_id
INNER JOIN `product_to_category` ptc ON p.product_id = ptc.product_id 
INNER JOIN `category_description` cd ON ptc.category_id = cd.category_id 
left join `order_product` op on op.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE 
op.product_id is null
ORDER BY p.quantity DESC LIMIT 1,100
```

You need to make sure that for all the joining conditions the corresponding columns are indexed and the following 2 indexes would be needed for resolving where and order by

```
alter table product add index quantity_idx(quantity);
alter table order_product add index product_id_idx(product_id);
```

You may use `explain select ...` to check the query health.

Comment: Note : indexing is compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the IN statement is taking time to execute.
I'd go with outer join here:

```
SELECT p.date_added, p.model, p.status, p.quantity, ptc.category_id, pd.name AS product_name, cd.name AS category_name FROM `product` p INNER JOIN `product_description` pd ON p.product_id= pd.product_id INNER JOIN `product_to_category` ptc INNER JOIN `category_description` cd ON ptc.category_id = cd.category_id ON p.product_id = ptc.product_id 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_product` op ON p.product_id = op.product_id WHERE op.order_product_id IS NULL
            ORDER BY p.quantity DESC LIMIT 1,100
```